# GParted -- Is this a good approach to move Linux Boot partition?

Tags: boot-loader, gparted

I have a split drive. The drive is 1Tb split into a Windows 11 partition (approx 250Gb) and a Zorin OS partition (the rest; 650Gb) .

I now find that the windows partition is short of space and the Zorin partition has lots of spare. I would like to expand the windows partition and reduce the Zorin one. Reading up about this there seem to be some potential serious pitfalls / hassles to moving the Zorin partition so that the bootloader (GRUB2) finds Zorin post-move.

I know there is documentation that is *simiiar* and I know there is a lot of documentation on the general principles of moving partitions, but wanted to double check my plan of attack here won't result in more hassle than minimum.

#### Current Status

This is how it currently looks `ext4` is the Zorin OS partition:

[image]

#### My Approach

1. On a boot USB (Zorin OS 16.4) use GParted to shrink the `ext4` by ~100Gb to ~512Gb. Move the partition to the right (with space of 1Mb)

   My intention:

   [image]
2. Then re-open GParted and expand the unallocated gap space to max size that should be set aside between these two partitions.
3. Then expand the NTFS windows 11 partition from ~247GB to fill the rest of the new space.

#### Other Guides:

I seem to see a lot of other posts and topics on a similar theme that show instead of expanding or shrinking partitions that they are instead made into "new" ones. I don't see the need for this in this instance and would like some confirmation my above process (shrink one then expand the other) can work?

#### Potential Issues:

1. I see that the Zorin OS data is all on the left so it will all need to be moved a bit to the right and so I believe the boot system (GRUB2) will need to be pointed to the new loading location. Is it likely any of these [GParted FAQ - fixing GRUB boot problems](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-fix-grub-boot-problem) will be required?
2. I would like to do this without needing to make any "new" intermediary partition, which I read often on this topic but I don't understand is necessary in this instance?
3. Is there any better way of doing this overall? Have I missed a glaring error?

Comment: Shouldn't **Step 1** be to make a full backup?

Comment: @JimL. in a perfect world; Yes. In the world I live in, I have no media to do that with sadly.

Comment: IF you do not have backups, then your data is not valuable. Just erase system, expand Windows NTFS only using Windows tools and reinstall. You should be able to move partition without grub issues. But you always need a Windows repair/recovery drive and Linux live system to make repairs if needed. Any partition change has chance to corrupt system. Issue most often is user caused, but hardware or software can also create problems. Good backups make problems easy to solve. Grub uses UUID and move moves do not change UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, taking a dive in, the above approach worked perfectly.

Took about 10 minutes to do and both systems loaded perfectly without incident.

yay!